# Storing and retrieving value inconsistency in a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am facing a weird problem. I have a table (observation_measurement) in oracle DB and it has many fields. One field name is observation_name. this observation_name field stores different measurements with it's value from a text file.
For example, observation_name stores four measurements a,b,c,d (name of the measurements) and their corresponding values 1,2,3,4 (values of those measurements).

Later it is reading same text file. This time that text file has three measurements a,b,d (c is not there) and their values are 7,8,9 and then store in the table. So, if I need the latest values for all observation_names then I should get a=7,b=8,c=null,d=9. But it is giving me
a=7,b=8,**c=3**,d=9. I dont know why it is getting old data for c measurement.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a bug in your code.  Oh, you wanted more?  In that case you need to post some details.  Show us the code which populates the data and the query which retrieves it.  Some sample data would be useful too.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` has to be handled specially in Oracle, like `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. 
Hope, your update logic involves some validation over the column and it leaves `NULL` values untreated.

Since, some validation fails because of `NULL`, the old value is retained in the table.
Can you please update your question with the Query used to `UPDATE` the table.